# Detect if User Profile photo is empty (happy face)

Tags: soql

My question is how can I detect if a user does not have a User Profile photo uploaded?  I can use the following SOQL to retrieve a User Profile images:

```
Select u.SmallPhotoUrl, u.FullPhotoUrl From User u
```

In testing, Salesforce returns a default happy face image url like this if no photo was uploaded: https://c.na5.content.force.com/profilephoto/005/F 
Here is a url returned for a user with an uploaded photo: https://c.na5.content.force.com/profilephoto/72970000000HO4F/F

Any ideas on how to detect the happy face without hard coding values?

Answer (score 3):

Personally I'd probably do this:

```
String url = 'https://c.na5.content.force.com/profilephoto/72970000000HO4F/F';
String[] parts = url.split('/');
Boolean isUploadedPhoto = parts[parts.size() - 2].length() == 15;
```

Comment: why not use custom setting instead as described bellow?

Comment: @AtulRajguru9 When you have settings in software, you have to add them to your code, document them and find a way to try to make sure they always get set (and someone will forget sometime). If you can fully automate instead (including having test cases) you avoid those problems. But if you are only talking about one or two orgs rather than code in a managed package the custom setting approach is lower risk.

Comment: Well i don't agree with some of points you said. Custom setting has default value so you don't need to worry about someone forgetting it. They are not too complicated than writing code so the way that we comment our code same way we can just add description of custom setting. Also this way your code becomes more compatible with future changes to happy face URL. Thoughts?

Comment: @AtulRajguru9 Good points. Its your code so your choice.

Comment: @AtulRajguru9 custom settings are only defaulted when the custom setting is created or edited. This doesn't cover the case where you are adding a new field to a custom setting that is already managed in an org. The user would need to edit the custom setting for the default value to appear.

Comment: Ok, I have updated my answer.

Comment: I have same issue. I tried with above code. for me its not working. Any other way to do it...?

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with a managed package then you could do the following:

**Step 1: Add a Custom Setting to store the default happy face URL**

**Step 2: Populate the custom setting using a Post Install Script**

You can setup a [Post Install Script](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=apex_post_install_script_intro.htm&language=en_US) that will run after a new version of your managed package is installed. The SOQL below could be used within the script:

```
Select u.SmallPhotoUrl, u.FullPhotoUrl From User where Id = :UserInfo.getUserId()
```

As the Post Install Script executes as a user that is setup especially for running the script (the user is deleted after the script runs), there will never be a photo uploaded for that user. The above SOQL will always return the default URL. You can then set your Custom Setting to that URL

**Step 3: Use your Custom Setting in Code**

You can now use the reference in your custom setting to see if the user has uploaded a photo.

**FYI: There is no guarantee that the default value will never change**

SalesForce could at any point in time, decide to change the default image which would mean the value stored in the custom setting is now incorrect.  One solution for this would be to always have one User that does not have an image uploaded and then query that user anytime you needed the default value. Example:

```
String defaultFullPhotoUrl = [
            Select u.FullPhotoUrl
            From User
            where Id = :knownUserWithNoPhoto.Id
            ].FullPhotoUrl;
```